# Swift WKwebView.evaluateJavaScript Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, swift-optionals

I want to execute javascript in an external screen's webview. In my main view I'm trying to call the `pop()` function in the External View like this:

```
let ex = ExternalDisplayViewController()
ex.pop(str: "Hello!")
```

When I run it I get "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" at `self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("go('\(str)')", completionHandler: nil)` in my External View:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ExternalDisplayViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    
    private var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
        config.setValue(true, forKey: "allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs")
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: config)
        webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        
        // load local html file
        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.absoluteURL
        let html = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("external.html")
        webView.loadFileURL(html, allowingReadAccessTo:bundleURL)
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }
    
    func pop(str: String) {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("go('\(str)')", completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

### EDIT (2023-03-01):

Sorry, I'm new to Swift and working with multiple views. If I use `viewDidLoad()` or `loadView()` I'm getting the same result:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ExternalDisplayViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    private var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
        config.setValue(true, forKey: "allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs")
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: config)
        webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        webView.uiDelegate = self

        // load local html file
        let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.absoluteURL
        let html = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("external.html")
        webView.loadFileURL(html, allowingReadAccessTo:bundleURL)
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    func pop(str: String) {
        if (self.isViewLoaded) {
            // viewController is visible
            print("view controller should be visible")
            self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("go('\(str)')", completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            print("view controller is not loaded")
            /*_ = self.view
            self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("go('\(str)')", completionHandler: nil)*/
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
View Loaded?
view controller is not loaded
```

How can I initialize this view so it's accessible?

Comment: your `WKWebView` is nil when you called the `pop` function. `viewWillLayoutSubviews` will only be called if `ExternalDisplayViewController`'s view bound changed. In your case, the view controller is not even presented yet.

Comment: Thanks @koropok ! Using ```viewDidLoad``` or ```loadView``` produces the same result (see EDIT above). How do I initialize the view controller properly? (I'm new to Swift so I really appreciate the guidance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to execute javascript in an external screen's webview.

I'm not completely sure of what you meant by external screen so I am assuming that you want to somehow init an `UIViewController` with a `WKWebView`, loads `external.html` from your bundle and executes a javascript function without presenting the view controller. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

(1) You should keep a strong reference to your `ExternalDisplayViewController` as Swift's [ARC](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/automaticreferencecounting/) might deallocate it. You should do something like this:

```
class MainDisplayViewController: UIViewController {

    let ex = ExternalDisplayViewController() 

    func foo() {
        self.ex.pop(str: "Hello!") // This might not work, will explain more in (3).
    }
}
```

(2) `UIViewController` lifecycle functions like `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews` won't be called until the its view is loaded into the view hierarchy. You can understand more about the lifecycle from [here](https://medium.com/@mediassumani49/understanding-the-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle-in-ios-a72a208a9b54).

The only function that will be called in `ExternalDisplayViewController` in your codes now is the `init` function, so you will have to move the `WKWebView` initialisation codes into it.

```
class ExternalDisplayViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
  
    init() {
        ... // Remember to super.init first before calling self.
        self.setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        ....
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
    }
}
```

(3) Depending on where and when you call your `pop` function, you might not be able to call the javascript function you desire from the webview because there will be a race condition between the webview loading of your html and calling of the javascript function. You can prevent this by using `WKNavigationDelegate`'s `didFinish` delegate function which will let you know when your webview has finish loading the html.

```
class ExternalDisplayViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    func setup() {
        ....
        self.webView.uiDelegate = self
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        ....
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("go('\(str)')", completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

(4) You can also consider moving your `WKWebView` codes into your main view controller since you are not planning to present your `ExternalDisplayViewController` (assuming my assumption is correct).

**UPDATE 2023-03-07**

The reason why it wasn't working is because you are actually initialising two different `ExternalDisplayViewController`.

**SceneDelegate**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    ....
    window.rootViewController = ExternalDisplayViewController()
    ....
}
```

**ViewController**

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    ....
    let ex = ExternalDisplayViewController()
    ....
}
```

This will not work because the `ExternalDisplayViewController` instance presented in your external display is initialised from `SceneDelegate`. The instance initialised in `ViewController` is not presented and basically does nothing and will be dealloc by ARC.

There are a few ways to resolve this. One of it is to use `NotificationCenter` as mentioned by the other answer, but do remember to remove the observer when you dismiss your `ExternalDisplayViewController` else it may become a [zombie](https://mobikul.com/zombie-objects-in-swift/) object.

Another way which is slightly more straightforward is to reference the `ExternalDisplayViewController` instance that has been presented in your external display directly from your `ViewController`.

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if message.name == "toEx", let msg = message.body as? String {
            guard let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.session.configuration.name == "External Display Configuration" })?.delegate as? SceneDelegate, let ex = sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? ExternalDisplayViewController else {
            return
        }
        ex.pop(str: msg)
    }
}
```

"External Display Configuration" is the name you provided for your scene configuration in `AppDelegate`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow - thanks so much for the response! For my iOS/iPadOS app, the “External Display/Screen” would be AirPlay Mirrored or HDMI adapter to a TV/Projector. When the extra screen is detected, external.html will load in full frame on the TV (not in the main app view/window). From the main view controller I’d to send to call JavaScript functions in external.html AND ultimately vice-versa (external.html send a message to the main view controller when a js function has completed. As long as the TV is attached/mirrored I’d like to be able to communicate with it. Does that change your understanding?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Is your `ExternalDisplayViewController` already presented on your external display?

Comment: Here's the sample project I'm working with: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tb7uw8r35madj29/ExtScreenSample.zip?dl=1 You can add the External View in Simulator > I/O > External Displays. It appears presented, but I'm unable to interact with it?

Comment: Referencing the instance from the ViewController worked perfectly - thank you so much for your help (and patience) :)

Answer (score 0):

When you write this line

```
let ex = ExternalDisplayViewController()
```

the web view will not load you have to push the view to the navigationController like this

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ex, animated: true)
```

after that you can call ex.pop(str: "str") but you have to gave it a little time until the view loads before calling this function so what you can do is at the end of the function viewDidLoad in the ExternalDisplayViewController add this

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "webViewDidLoad"), object: nil)
```

and instead of calling ex.pop(str: "Hello!") write this code instead

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "webViewDidLoad"), object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
        ex.pop(str: "str")
    }
```

But make sure your viewController has a navigationController when you call self.navigationController